# Detecting exif with Image::ExifTool

Tags: perl, exiftool

I'm using Image::ExifTool for my exif-needs.

But now, need ONLY to detect if an image has EXIF data or not, and Image::ExifTool returns some data all times (e.g. returns metadata from file stat too, and internal image detecting). So,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Image::ExifTool qw(:Public);
use Data::Dumper;

my $ext = new Image::ExifTool;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    next unless(-f $path);
    if( $ext->ExtractInfo($path) ) {
        say "$_" for (sort $ext->GetFoundTags());
    }
    else {
        say "NO\t$path";
    }
}
```

prints many "Found" tags, but the file doesn't contain any exif information.

**Is here some easy way how to detect than the image really has or not EMBEDEDD exif data with Image::ExifTool?**

If someone need additional informations: Having and image `img.jpg` with exif data, so:

```
$ exif --list-tags --no-fixup img.jpg

#or
$ identify -format '%[exif:*]' img.jpg
```

print many tags. Now

```
$ cp img.jpg img2.jpg
$ mogrify -strip img2.jpg   #removing all exif data, so

$ exif --list-tags --no-fixup img2.jpg
```

prints

```
Corrupt data
The data provided does not follow the specification.
ExifLoader: The data supplied does not seem to contain EXIF data.
```

and

```
$ identify -format '%[exif:*]' img2.jpg
```

prints nothing. So the `img2.jpg` hasn't exif data. But the above perl script still prints many "Found" tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling $ext->GetInfo('EXIF:*') to get only the EXIF information.

- Phil

Comment: ++ :) This is exactly what is missing in the doccu. Sure, here is some examples like "exif:iso" - but exactly how to gather only EXIF info is missing. THANK YOU.

Comment: I think you missed this in the ImageInfo() argument descriptions: **"Thus 'GROUP:*' represents all tags in a specific group"**.  And the GetInfo() argument description refers to ImageInfo() since these arguments are the same for both functions.